# Opening TIFF image in PIL (Python)?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, python-imaging-library

I'm new to Python and trying to work with TIFF images using the following  code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy 

im = Image.open('LakeEx.tif') 
imarray = numpy.array(im) 
imarray.shape 
im.show()
```

and I got this error:

> "ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image"

Is there any specific criteria to the TIFF file to work with Python: size, bit,... etc?

Comment: Consider using `gdal` instead of PIL

Comment: As commented by @DmitriChubarov. Have a look at this answer, a gdal method to read geotiff is provided: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/285685/98816

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PIL wants to see a ".tiff" at the end of the file name. You have ".tif". The solution is to rename your file to "LakeEx.tiff".