# convert tiff to UInt16 PNG turns black

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

Im using to `gdal_translate` to create tiled DEM, `tif(float32) -> PNG (UInt16)`.
All the images trun out black.
When I change `UInt` to `byte` - everything work as expected.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import os, gdal

in_path = 'C:\\xxx\\'
input_filename = 'input.tif'

out_path = 'C:\\xxx\\'
output_filename = 'tile_x'

tile_size_x = 8129
tile_size_y = 8129
ds = gdal.Open(in_path + input_filename)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
xsize = band.XSize
ysize = band.YSize

xCnt, yCnt = -1, -1

for i in range(0, xsize, tile_size_x):
    xCnt = xCnt+1
    yCnt = -1
    for j in range(0, ysize, tile_size_y):
        yCnt = yCnt+1
        com_string = "gdal_translate -of PNG -ot UInt16 -srcwin " + str(i)+ ", " + str(j) + ", " + str(tile_size_x) + ", " + str(tile_size_y) + " " + str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(xCnt) + "_y" + str(yCnt) + ".png"
        os.system(com_string)
```

Comment: Run `gdalinfo -hist`. Is the histogram biased to the low end? If your viewer is utilizing the full UInt16 scale but all the data is near the black end the image appear black. What viewer do you use? Can it apply Min-Max stretch or some other contrast enhancement?

Comment: Can you try using the method shown in [Editing .tiff rasters in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/285685/98816) and add an .astype(np.uint16) to the numpy array? This would avoid to lose the geolocation of the DTM